# What is the meaning of "python3 -u"?

Tags: python, command-line

When running a Python file from the command line, you use `python3 <file>`, but VSCode Code Runner uses `python3 -u <file>` (by default), so I was wondering:

1. What's the difference (since after testing I see no visible
   difference)?
2. What is the `-u` part called?

Comment: "-u     Force  stdin,  stdout  and  stderr to be totally unbuffered.  On
              systems where it matters, also put stdin, stdout and  stderr  in
              binary  mode.   Note  that there is internal buffering in xread‐
              lines(), readlines() and file-object  iterators  ("for  line  in
              sys.stdin")  which  is  not  influenced by this option.  To work
              around this, you will want to use "sys.stdin.readline()"  inside
              a "while 1:" loop."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-u` flag, according to Python's `--help` statement:

> force the binary I/O layers of stdout and stderr to be unbuffered; stdin is always buffered; text I/O layer will be line-buffered; also PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x

This is [documented here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u) in the Python docs.

These are known as command line options. There are a number of them, which you can read about using `python3 --help`.